# `Getter` is not retrieving true value outside `Setter` block

Tags: java, csv, foreach, setter, getter

I am trying to import 2 different rows as a list from 2 different CSV files.

From one CSV file fetching `shareNumberList`and `multiplierList` from another CSV file.

Then trying to set the values of `shareNumberList` and `multiplierList` in another list `inputCalculationList` using foreach loop.

While trying to fetch value inside setter block(#1 & #2), then getting proper value. But while trying to fetch value from another code block(#3) Then getting zero.Though I have added setter values in a list which is declared globally.

`inputCalculationList.add(inputCalculation)`

Then why I am not getting values from another block?

My full code:

```
public class CSVFileRWFileHandler {

    public static List<InputCalculation> inputCalculationList = new ArrayList<InputCalculation>();
    public static List<ShareNumber> shareNumberList = new ArrayList<ShareNumber>();
    public static List<Multiplier> multiplierList = new ArrayList<Multiplier>();
    public static InputCalculation inputCalculation = new InputCalculation();

public static void readCsvFile(String fileName, 
    List<InterMediateCalculation> imCalculationList) {

    ReadFilesForCalcImpl rfc = new ReadFilesForCalcImpl();
    //getting *shareNumberList*
    rfc.readShareNumberSheet(Constant.readShareNunmerFileLocation, shareNumberList); 
    //getting *multiplierList*
    rfc.readMultiplierSheet(Constant.readMultiplierFileLocation, multiplierList);
 }
 public static void writeCsvFile(String fileName) {     
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;               
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
        fileWriter.append(Constant.FILE_HEADER);            
        fileWriter.append(Constant.NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);            

       //block #1:
      for (Multiplier multiplier : multiplierList) {
           // setter for inputCalculation
           inputCalculation.setMultiplierAW(multiplier.getMultiplierAW());
           // getter for inputCalculation
           System.out.println(inputCalculation.getMultiplierAW());//This line prints proper value
           inputCalculationList.add(inputCalculation);              
       }
       //block #2:
       for (ShareNumber shareNumber : shareNumberList) {    
            // setter for inputCalculation                  
          inputCalculation.setShareNumberAW(shareNumber.getShareNumberAW());    
          // getter for inputCalculation
          System.out.println(inputCalculation.getShareNumberAW());//This line prints proper value
          inputCalculationList.add(inputCalculation);               
       }
      //block #3:       
      for (InputCalculation inputCalculation : inputCalculationList) {
          System.out.println(inputCalculation.getShareNumberAW());//This line don't print proper value. Getting '0' 
          System.out.println(inputCalculation.getMultiplierAW());   //This line don't print proper value. Getting '0'

          fileWriter.append(inputCalculation.getShareNumberAW()); //getter not fetchging original value.
          fileWriter.append(Constant.COMMA_DELIMITER);
          fileWriter.append(inputCalculation.getMultiplierAW());  //getter not fetchging original value.
          fileWriter.append(Constant.NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

       }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
       } 
  }
```

`readMultiplierSheet` method:

```
 public void readMultiplierSheet(String readfileName, List<Multiplier> multiplierList) {
    BufferedReader fileReader = null;       
    try {
        String line = "";
        fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readfileName));
        fileReader.readLine();
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split(Constant.COMMA_DELIMITER);   
            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                Multiplier multiplier = new Multiplier(tokens[Constant.Cell_INDEX_OF_AW], tokens[Constant.Cell_INDEX_OF_AX]);
                multiplierList.add(multiplier);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in CsvFileReader !!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing fileReader !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

`readShareNumberSheet` method is similar to `readMultiplierSheet` method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: inputCalculationList has the final setMultiplierAW after quitting the first loop (block #1). You're only changing setShareNumberAW in block #2

Comment: Is the last for loop closed after the prints, or is there logic as well?  Is it only some of the values printing 0, or all of them?  Does your getter only get the value, or does it have other logic?

Comment: I have included all code related to getter & setter which are necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Lance Toth. Then, should I get the value of setShareNumberAW in block #2? But I am getting 0.

Comment: @phflack. yes closed. Unfortunatelly I have missed that. Now edited.

Comment: Where is the getter/setter code?  Is the output being printed out half correct?

Comment: @ phflack, output is being printed fully wrong. Just 0.
From 1st & 2nd block printing right values. From 3rd block printing wrong values.

Comment: Now it is proved that for solving my problem there was no need of enough code. That was sufficient what I added at first. Some people are downvoting without understanding the problem. I think actually they are not understanding the problem. If they don't understand or can't solve why do they downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a single loop and recreating each item in it, similarly to this

```
for(int index = 0; index < multiplierList.length; index++){
  public static List<InputCalculation> inputCalculationList = new ArrayList<InputCalculation>();

  inputCalculation.setMultiplierAW( multiplierList.get(index).getMultiplierAW());

  inputCalculation.setShareNumberAW( shareNumberList.get(index).getShareNumberAW());  
  inputCalculationList.add(inputCalculation); 
}
```

Comment: According to your suggested code,I have added setter values in a list which is declared globally.

`inputCalculationList.add(inputCalculation)`

Should I not get values of inputCalculationList from another block?

Comment: @Sourov you can put the fileWriter.append lines into the same block, if that's what you mean. If you don't use the list for anything else, that move renders the list redundant.

Comment: Yes, If I put `fileWriter.append` inside same block then this problem solves. But actually, I have many other calculations with this list. So I tried to set data in the list from `block #1` and `block  #2` and kept the list as global. BTW now I am doing according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
//block #1:
>       for (Multiplier multiplier : multiplierList) {
>            // setter for inputCalculation
>            inputCalculation.setMultiplierAW(multiplier.getMultiplierAW());
>            // getter for inputCalculation
>            System.out.println(inputCalculation.getMultiplierAW());//This line
> prints proper value
>            inputCalculationList.add(inputCalculation);              
>        }
```

I think you can keep your existing implementation after change inside the foreach loop inputCalculation object creation every time. but it's not a good approach.

Comment: Are you saying about `inputCalculation` object instantiation using the constructor? 
If yes, I have tried with that. But in vain.

Comment: Actually, this approach won't work here. Why not I am explaining as another answer. So, need to work as suggested by Lance Toth.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have set the values in `shareNumberList` and `multiplierList` via constructor:

```
ShareNumber shareNumber = new ShareNumber(tokens[Constant.Cell_INDEX_OF_AW]); 
shareNumberList.add(shareNumber);

Multiplier multiplier = new Multiplier(tokens[Constant.Cell_INDEX_OF_AW], tokens[Constant.Cell_INDEX_OF_AX]);
multiplierList.add(multiplier);
```

If I try here using constructor my code will be like this_

```
InputCalculation inputCalculation = new InputCalculation(hareNumber.getShareNumberAW(), multiplier.getMultiplierAW());
```

From `block #1` I am getting `multiplier.getMultiplierAW()` and `block #2` I am getting `shareNumber.getShareNumberAW()`.

So I can't get 2 values at the same time from a single block. So can't instantiate using constructor here.

That's why I have to do the following way_

```
for(int index = 0; index < shareNumberList.size(); index++){

    inputCalculation.setMultiplierAW( multiplierList.get(index).getMultiplierAW());
    inputCalculation.setShareNumberAW( shareNumberList.get(index).getShareNumberAW());  

    // others calculation
    // Write in file as output.
    ...............................................

}
```